# Firefox addon sdk: retrieving value from a different site based on clipboard content

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I just got started with firefox addons to help my team fasten up our work, what i am trying to create:
When being on a specific site (let's call it **mysite.com/input**) i want to fill out automatically an input with an id: "textinput" from the value that is **stored on the clipboard**. 
Yeah it is simple yet it would be simply enough to paste it, wouldn't it?... now here is the twist:

I need an other form of the value: on the clipboard it is x/y/z. There is a database site (let's call it database.com) on which searching like **database.com?s=x/y/z** would directly give the page from where it is possible to gain the correct value as it has an id: #result

I got lost how to properly communicate between page and content scripts, i'm not even sure in what order should i use the pagemod and the page-worker

Please help me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic flow is this:

- In your content script, you get the value form the form, somehow. I'll leave that up to you.
- Still in the content script, you send the data to main.js using self.port.emit:

Code:

```
self.port.emit('got-my-value', myValue);
```

- In main.js, you would then receive the 'got-my-value' event and make a cross-domain request using the request module.

Code:

```
require('page-mod').PageMod({
    include: 'somesite.com',
    contentScriptFile: data.url('somescript.js'),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('got-my-value', function(value) {
            require('request').Request({
                url: 'http://someurl.com',
                onComplete: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    // maybe send data back to worker?
                    worker.port.emit('got-other-data', response.json);
                }
            }).post();
        });
    }
});
```

- If you need to receive the data back in the original worker, you would another listener for the event coming back.

Code:

```
self.port.on('got-other-data', function(value) {
    // do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing :) How could i work with the "request" result? i had to change to "response.text" as it would send an object. I need only a part of the "someurl.com" which is fortunately under an #ID

It now works like this:

´            require('request').Request({
                url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+value,
                onComplete: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    // maybe send data back to worker?
                    worker.port.emit('got-other-data', response.text);
                }
            }
´

Comment: Sorry i could not format it for code... Also what does .post(); in this case?

Comment: The docs for the request module are available here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue for the past 2 days until I found this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts

They indicate the following:

> However, you can enable these features for specific domains by adding
>   them to your add-on's **package.json** under the "cross-domain-content"
>   key, which itself lives under the "permissions" key:

```
 "permissions": {
     "cross-domain-content": ["http://example.org/", "http://example.com/"] }
```

> The domains listed must include the scheme
>   and fully qualified domain name, and these must exactly match the
>   domains serving the content - so in the example above, the content
>   script will not be allowed to access content served from
>   https://example.com/. Wildcards are not allowed. This feature is
>   currently only available for content scripts, not for page scripts
>   included in HTML files shipped with your add-on.

That did the trick for me.